# Read a file to variable then replace control charactors with escape charecters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file like below

```
 # cat test
Start   tab
enter
```

or  with control characters

```
# cat -A test
Start^Itab$
enter$
```

I want to convert file to a variable exactly like below

```
file = "Start\ttab\nenter"  

echo -e $file
Start   tab
enter
```

How we can achieve this  just using bash script (without using any programming languages like perl or python).

Please note : Given file here is just sample , I really have very big files with complex control characters , so 'sed' like methods will not work here.

Comment: `echo -e <"$file"` might work. Good luck.

Comment: You want a script that takes  a text file, and produces a second script that (when run) reproduces the original file? That's *far* too broad a question.

Answer (score 1):

```
mapfile data < /path/to/file
```

will store the file as array in data

```
printf '%s' "${data[@]}"
```